# Create Apriori itemset on Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, apriori

My goal is to use the Apriori algorithm to find out interesting insights from the purchase table which is created on AWS Redshift. The purchase table looks like the below table.

```
-------------
ID | product
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    A
2    C
```

I'm able to count the frequency of product and filter those observations with low frequency. However, I had a difficult time creating the rules of the itemset in the AWS Redshift environment. This is what I want to get:

```
------------------
itemset | count(*)
A,B       1
A,C       2
B,C       1
```

There are more than 1000 products in the purchase table so I'd like to learn how to write an effective and efficient query to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a self-join:

```
select t1.product, t2.product, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.product < t2.product
group by t1.product, t2.product;
```

This puts the item sets in two columns.  You can concatenate them together as well:

```
select t1.product || ',' || t2.product, count(*)
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.product < t2.product
group by t1.product, t2.product
order by t1.product || ',' || t2.product;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/21674) is a SQL Fiddle illustrating that the code works.

Comment: Hi Gordon! thank you so much for your solution! But I have a quick question about your answer. Could you please kindly explain how "t1.product < t2.product" works in this query? Much appreciated

Comment: The count(*) is not correct when I inspected the observations in the purchase table

Comment: @Abbey . . . The `<` is so "A,B" is in the result set but not "B,A".

Comment: @Abbey . . . The code works.  I just added a demonstration.

Comment: got it! so basically the "<" helps to order items according to its alphabets! Thank you so much